# How do all requests end up in routes.rb in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I want to set up simple CGI application which would work on any request (say `/` or `/hello/`, `/bye` and so on I would have to set up, for example, `.htaccess` file which would redirect any request to my `script.rb`

But how do all requests end up in `routes.rb` or in another words - where is the starting point of Rails application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a presentation about request life cycle in Rails http://www.slideshare.net/lachie/the-rails-request-cycle

Answer (score 1):

This is quite good overview how Rails dispatcher works: http://brainspl.at/request_response.pdf